# jQuery clearQueue not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX function that displays a notification upon success. However it is possible the user calls it a few times within a short period of time thus creating a que of notifications. I am trying to eliminate the que and show the notification once

**AJAX FUNCTION**

```
function update(updateid, div) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'file.php', 
        data: {"updateid":updateid,"div":div},
        success: function(data) {
             $('.notification').html(data).hide().fadeIn(300);
             $('.notification').delay(2000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

Ive tried adding clearQueue() a few times

This prevents the notification from working

```
$('.notification').html(data).hide().fadeIn(300).clearQueue();
$('.notification').delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

This prevents the notification from fading out

```
 $('.notification').html(data).hide().fadeIn(300);
 $('.notification').delay(2000).fadeOut().clearQueue();
```

Obviously im not using clearQueue(); properly, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.notification').clearQueue().delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

use clearQueue() before delay.

---

You can also use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd)

```
$('.notification').stop(true,true).delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: hmm doesnt seem to be working, nothing happens... my console isnt showing any errors either, weird

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a flag varible.

`var notificationShowing = false;
    [...]
    success: function(data) {
        if (!notificationShowing) {
            notificationShowing = true;
            $('.notification').html(data).hide().fadeIn(300);
            $('.notification').delay(2000).fadeOut(function() { notificationShowing = false});
        }
    }`